# Unable to access Rails app on Apache + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am trying to setup a basic Rails app with Apache and Passenger on Ubuntu. I am able to start WEBrick on the server, but not through Apache.

Here is my app's conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName blog.dev
  DocumentRoot /var/blog/current/public
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/blog-access_log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/blog-error_log
   <Directory /var/blog/current/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the passenger conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.24/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.24
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
PassengerMaxPoolSize 5
PassengerPoolIdleTime 90
PassengerMaxRequests 10000
```

I do have Apache and passenger installed correctly (as well as the Apache module for Passenger). When I do `curl localhost`, the generic Apache page is shown and not my app. I haven't seen anything in the Apache error logs that would indicate a failure. Is there something I am missing to get this to work?

EDIT: I am able to hit `blog.dev` using `curl`, but it returns the default Apache page and not the Rails default page. Here is the entry in the `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   blog.dev
```

Also, when I run `sudo passenger-stats`, I don't see my application in the Application groups. I am guessing that Passenger is the problem here, but I can't seem to find out what is going on.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after modifying the conf file?

Comment: Yep both by doing `apache2 restart` and `apache2ctl restart`

Comment: is your application in the current folder?

Comment: Yep all of the paths are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set ServerName in your config to be `blog` - that means it will respond to requests for the domain `blog`. You should set this to the domain you actually want to use to serve the blog on.

Comment: What should the server name be? I don't have a domain for it. I am testing it in a local VM right now -- I tried putting both `localhost` nd the VM IP address I set up in vagrant, but they don't work.

Comment: if this isn't actually for a production server, it's a bit different - whatever name you put in there (and it can be anything, usually in development I use .dev domains like `schools.dev`) then you have to modify your hosts file so that your computer knows that schools.dev actually resolves to localhost.

Comment: Add another line in your `/etc/hosts` file with the domain name and your IP.

Comment: Tried by putting `www.blog.dev localhost` and `blog.dev localhost` in `/etc/hosts` and restarted apache, but it was unable to resolve the host. I also tried it with the IP address for the VM, but it did not work either.

Comment: Did you also change the ServerName in the Apache config to be blog.dev ?

Comment: are you trying to access this over http or https? Also have you done this configuration in your local system or any cloud space ex- ec2

Comment: The changes which come into consideration is only /var/blog/current/public,also if your apache restarts with no errors. The configuration looks good. apache2.conf serves http request by default

Comment: Ah ok in `hosts` I had blog.dev and the IP address backwards. I am able to `curl` blog.dev, but it returns the default Apache page and not the default Rails page (since it is the blank Rails app that I am working with for now). I updated the files above as well.

Comment: I am trying to access it via http in a local system.

Comment: Got it working! Adding `www.blog.dev` to `/etc/hosts` and I was able to hit the Rails app. Thanks!